# Docker can't connect to MySQL running docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using this Docker config: https://github.com/romaricp/kit-starter-symfony-4-docker

I start the environment by using:

> docker-compose build

followed by:

> docker-compose up -d

Everything is running fine but there is a problem with MySQL service. I get an Symfony error:

> "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"

as well as PMA error when I try to login to DB:

> mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name does not resolve

Any idea how could I make it work?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: sf4_apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
    depends_on:
      - php

mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
        MYSQL_USER: sf4
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4

php:
    build: .docker/php
    container_name: sf4_php
    volumes:
      - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
    environment:
      - maildev_host=sf4_maildev
    depends_on:
      - maildev
      - mysql

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: sf4_phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql

maildev:
    image: djfarrelly/maildev
    container_name: sf4_maildev
    ports:
      - 8001:80
```

Also I opened the mysql logs and I see this:

> 2019-04-07T12:00:30.943414Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Maybe the port is wrong and that's why I can't connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `phpmyadmin` service, i think you should set the `PMA_HOST` and `PMA_PORT` environment variables like this:

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: sf4_phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql
```

Your mysql container should have the `command` instruction at the start to set the authentication plugin (there is an issue with the connectors with mysql 8), more details [here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/)

```
mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
        MYSQL_USER: sf4
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4
```

in your Symfony app, the connection string is located in `.env` file, and it should have the following format :

> DATABASE_URL=mysql://**mysql_user**:**mysql_user_password**@**mysql_host**:**mysql_port**/**db_name**
>
> **mysql_user**: your mysql user (ex: root)
>
> **mysql_user_password**: the user's password (ex: root)
>
> **mysql_host**: is should contain your mysql container service name
>   located in your `docker-compose.yml` file (mysql in this case)
>
> **mysql_port**: mysql container internal port (3306, in this case)
>
> **db_name**: the database you want to connect to.

the DATABASE_URL can look like this :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/sf4
```

stop your containers after these changes and start them up again.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Tried your settings, this way I get an The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] error.

Comment: While trying to login to PMA. Also Symfony can't reach the DB also. I changed the .env database credentials to DATABASE_URL=mysql://sf4:root@mysql:3306/sf4

Comment: Same errors. Also my login credentials should be sf4/root if I'm correct. Based on Docker environment parameters.

Comment: this line is missing in your docker-compose.yml (mysql service) 
`command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"`

Comment: Same thing, I ran docker-compose down and docker-compose up -d after changing it and the error is same.

Comment: Also if I enter a non existing user name as example "test". Then I get the error Access denied for user 'test'@'172.30.0.4' (using password: NO). So it can see the "root" and "sf4" users but something is wrong with the authentication.

Comment: yes, there is an issue with the authentication, that's why the command instruction is required, but it seems it has no effect in your setup, i will update my answer with some details about it.

Comment: try connecting with mysql cli or phpmyadmin to isolate the problem . With different client are you able to connect or not.

Comment: Refer this instead of giving mysql keyword -provide the service name as mysqldb . Ref here : https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml and mention the dependency in web as well. instead of directy trying with symfony frameowkr , try with phpmyadmin (or) mysql cli inside the connector.

Comment: Wow, removing .docker from volumes: - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql helped and PMA is working fine now. Still, Symfony doesn't connect to DB yet. The config is DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/sf4 any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Is the sf4 database viewable in phpmyadmin when you login as root ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose the mysql port 3306:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    volumes:
    - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
        MYSQL_USER: sf4
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4
    networks:
    - default
```

Comment: This way I get an error: {"message":"driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sf4_mysql (4c503802716b745c597590bf6a5b251b6d3b24c31ddd2618b3f8b380ac677442): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated"}

Comment: Your 3306 is already used by another service in you host machine, try `"3307:3306"`, or leave as it is and stop the mysql service in your host machine.

Comment: try: docker-compose down & docker-compose up -d
More info: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4950 about this issue.

Comment: Tried restarting it, nothing changed, also changed the port for mysql on Docker to 3307:3306 and nothing changed.

Comment: Good idea @AbdelkarimELAMEL. Stop other mysql-services ;)

Comment: @The50 : do you have mysql installed in your host machine ?

Comment: I checked it and it seems that there is no mysql installed on my host machine. type -a mysql gives nothing. I am running OS X.

Comment: docker-compose down & 
docker rm -fv $(docker ps -aq) & 
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 3306
 \ 
kill -9 <process id>

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having trouble linking the containers. I suggest that you use a custom network instead of linking. That all containers can see each other